# insert rows in a table with value in a column that is different for each row inserted

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT,product_id INT,sent_at datetime);
CREATE TABLE products(id INT);
```

I want to create a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(product_id,sent_at)
    SELECT products.id as product_id,
    DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) as sent_at
    FROM products;
```

I have 1000 rows in the `products` table and I want a different value for the `sent_at` column for each of the rows in the `test` table.
The `sent_at` column should be increment by 10 more minutes for each row of the `products` table inserted.
I don't want the same value for `sent_at` column for all the rows in `test` table.

AND I CANNOT use a procedure. I am using MySQL 5.7.

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

works verywell on mysql

```
mysql> select * from products;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|   23 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test(product_id,sent_at)
    ->     SELECT products.id as product_id,
    ->     DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) as sent_at
    ->     FROM products;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+------+------------+---------------------+
| id   | product_id | sent_at             |
+------+------------+---------------------+
| NULL |         23 | 2017-07-20 19:26:36 |
+------+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```